# problem when i try create a new folder using mkdir - PermissionError: [WinError 5]

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to create a new folder in the path `C: / Program Files (x86)` this folder would be the folder called `Alpha` for lp which I am using this code:

```
import shutil
import os

os.mkdir('C:/Program Files (x86)/Alfa')
```

to be able to create the specified directory but it does not work

In the same way try to create the file and just copy it to the directory to do this:
`shutil.copy (" origen.txt", 'C: / Program Files (x86)')`

but the same error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\copy.py", line 5, in <module>
    shutil.copy("origen.txt", 'C:/Program Files(x86)')
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 241, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Program Files(x86)'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Try to run script/command line as an admin, should do the job

Comment: `'C: / Program Files (x86)'` is not the same as `'C:/Program Files (x86)'`. You need to pay attention to details like this as a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not because your code doesn't work or there's something wrong with it but because the user you are running the script with does not have access to write into that particular location.

Comment: ,there is a way to generate a dialog box or an action that forced the execution of this script as administrator

Comment: See, esdras's answer and use tkinter to show a dialog instead of just printing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the method... Jus for a try. But I think is something wrong about your user or something like that.

```
try:
    os.makedirs(str(path))
except OSError as e:
    print(e)
```